# CSVHelper: dynamically write to CSV

Tags: c#, csv, unity-game-engine, csvhelper

Let's say I have the following interface:

```cs
public interface IStateInformation
{
    public int TaskId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

and the following class implementing this interface:

```cs
public class ExternalStateInformation : IStateInformation
{
    public int TaskId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string External { get; set; }
}
```

Now I want to write the following class to a CSV:

```cs
public class SwitchingData
{
    public string DateTime { get; set; }
    public int EpisodeId { get; set; }
    public IStateInformation SourceState { get; set; }
    public IStateInformation TargetState { get; set; }
}
```

As you can see, this class includes `IStateInformation` objects. When I try to write a record to a CSV file, only the properties of `IStateInformation` are considered (`TaskId` and `Name`) even when e.g. `SourceState` is of type `ExternalStateInformation` (therefore `External` is missing). My question is, how can I write the properties of a dynamic type instead of the static one?
I tried to use `ClassMap` but without success.

**Details**

The writing script looks like this:

```cs
...         
using (var stream = File.Open(path, FileMode.Append))
using (var writer = new StreamWriter(stream))
using (var csv = new CsvWriter(writer, config))
{
     if(type != null)
     {
         csv.Context.RegisterClassMap(type);
     }
                
     csv.Context.TypeConverterOptionsCache.AddOptions<DateTime>(options);
     csv.Context.TypeConverterOptionsCache.AddOptions<DateTime?>(options);
     csv.WriteRecords(data);
}
...
```

where `type` was the `ClassMap` I played with.

Comment: Does your CSV serializer have a mechanism that can be used to provide it with metadata informationm Of you think about it, doing something like this would be very complicated. If you had a collection that included _many_ different implementations of `IStateInformation`, the CSV writer would need to grab metadata from each one before it wrote the first line of output (so that it would know what colums are to be written for each record)

Comment: Thanks, make sense. In the end I changed the way how I write the records to the CSV to solve my issue (see my answer).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end I have written my own functions writing the header and the records. My given example would lead to the following header:

`DateTime,EpisodeId,SourceState_TaskId,SourceState_Name,SourceState_External,TargetState_TaskId,TargetState_Name,TargetState_External`

If `TargetState` would implement the `IStateInformation` interface with another additional property, let's say `Internal`, the header would look like:

`DateTime,EpisodeId,SourceState_TaskId,SourceState_Name,SourceState_External,TargetState_TaskId,TargetState_Name,TargetState_External,TargetState_Internal`

**General Writing Function**

```
private static void WriteToCSV<T>(string path, TypeConverterOptions options, List<T> data, FileMode mode)
{
    using (var stream = File.Open(path, mode))
    using (var writer = new StreamWriter(stream))
    using (var csv = new CsvWriter(writer, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture))
    {
        csv.Context.TypeConverterOptionsCache.AddOptions<DateTime>(options);
        csv.Context.TypeConverterOptionsCache.AddOptions<DateTime?>(options);

        List<Type> structure = GetStructureOfCSV(csv, data);

        if (mode == FileMode.Create)
        {
            WriteHeaderToCSV(csv, data);
            csv.NextRecord();
        }

        foreach (var record in data)
        {
            WriteRecordToCSV(csv, record, structure);
            csv.NextRecord();
        }
    }

    if (mode == FileMode.Create)
    {
        Debug.Log(String.Format("Write data to new file {0}", path));
    }
    else if (mode == FileMode.Append)
    {
        Debug.Log(String.Format("Write data to existing file {0}", path));
    }
}
```

**Function to get the Structure of the Object**

This is needed to write default values instead of null values which would lead to too less CSV fields.

```
    private static List<Type> GetStructureOfCSV<T>(CsvWriter csv, List<T> data)
    {
        BindingFlags bindingFlags = BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.Public;
        MemberInfo[] members = data[0].GetType().GetMemberInfos(bindingFlags);
        List<Type> structure = new List<Type>
        {
            data[0].GetType()
        };

        foreach (var thisVar in members)
        {
            if (!HasCSVHelperBuiltInConverter(thisVar.GetUnderlyingType()))
            {
                try
                {
                    List<T> records = data.Where(x => thisVar.GetValue(x) != null).ToList();
                    List<object> values = records.Select(x => thisVar.GetValue(x)).ToList();
                    structure = structure.Concat(GetStructureOfCSV(csv, values)).ToList();
                }
                catch (InvalidOperationException)
                {
                }
            }
        }

        return structure;
    }
```

**Check for ReferenceConverter**

```
    private static bool HasCSVHelperBuiltInConverter(Type type)
    {
        return TypeDescriptor.GetConverter(type).GetType() != typeof(ReferenceConverter);
    }
```

**Header**

```
    private static void WriteHeaderToCSV<T>(CsvWriter csv, List<T> data, string prefix = "")
    {
        BindingFlags bindingFlags = BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.Public;
        MemberInfo[] members = data[0].GetType().GetMemberInfos(bindingFlags);

        foreach (var thisVar in members)
        {
            if (!HasCSVHelperBuiltInConverter(thisVar.GetUnderlyingType()))
            {
                try
                {
                    List<T> records = data.Where(x => thisVar.GetValue(x) != null).ToList();
                    List<object> values = records.Select(x => thisVar.GetValue(x)).ToList();
                    WriteHeaderToCSV(csv, values, thisVar.Name);
                }
                catch (InvalidOperationException)
                {
                    csv.WriteField(thisVar.Name);
                }
            }
            else
            {
                if (prefix != "" && prefix != null)
                {
                    csv.WriteField(string.Format("{0}_{1}", prefix, thisVar.Name));
                }
                else
                {
                    csv.WriteField(thisVar.Name);
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

**Records**

```
    private static void WriteRecordToCSV(CsvWriter csv, object record, List<Type> structure)
    {
        BindingFlags bindingFlags = BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.Public;
        MemberInfo[] members = record.GetType().GetMemberInfos(bindingFlags);
        List<Type> local_structure = new List<Type>(structure);

        local_structure.RemoveAt(0);

        foreach (var thisVar in members)
        {
            if (!HasCSVHelperBuiltInConverter(thisVar.GetUnderlyingType()))
            {
                if(thisVar.GetValue(record) != null)
                {
                    WriteRecordToCSV(csv, thisVar.GetValue(record), local_structure);
                }
                else
                {
                    object instance = Activator.CreateInstance(local_structure.First());
                    csv.WriteRecord(instance);
                }
            }
            else
            {
                csv.WriteField(thisVar.GetValue(record));
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

It's not pretty, but it appears that this `ClassMap` would work.

```cs
public sealed class SwitchingDataClassMap : ClassMap<SwitchingData>
{
    public SwitchingDataClassMap() 
    {
        Map(m => m.DateTime).Index(0);
        Map(m => m.EpisodeId).Index(1);
        Map(m => m.SourceState.TaskId).Name("SourceStateTaskId").Index(2);
        Map(m => m.SourceState.Name).Name("SourceStateName").Index(3);
        Map(m => ((ExternalStateInformation)m.SourceState).External)
            .Convert(args => args.Value.SourceState is ExternalStateInformation ?
                    ((ExternalStateInformation)args.Value.SourceState).External :
                    null)
            .Name("SourceStateExternal").Index(4);
        Map(m => m.TargetState.TaskId).Name("TargetStateTaskId").Index(5);
        Map(m => m.TargetState.Name).Name("TargetStateName").Index(6);
        Map(m => ((ExternalStateInformation)m.TargetState).External)
            .Convert(args => args.Value.TargetState is ExternalStateInformation ?
                    ((ExternalStateInformation)args.Value.TargetState).External :
                    null)
            .Name("TargetStateExternal").Index(7);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but this is coupled to the `ExternalStateInformation` class but I want a generic solution that prints the properties of any class, which implements `IStateInformation`, dynamically.

Comment: Unfortunately, `CsvHelper` is going to need to know the class type at compile time in order to map the properties.  You can do the mapping yourself at runtime using reflection, but I have a feeling you are going to take a speed hit.